# The function strcmp() work in if statement , but not in else if , why?

Tags: c

i am writing the inch-centimeter conversion code , and i want when my input is "Cm" or "cm" it will convert from centimeter to inch , and vice versa with "Inch" and "inch"  , but when i input anything , the output is the same when i write "Cm" or "cm" , i don't know what is the problem , i will be very grateful if you help me , Thanks!

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()

{
    double i, cm;
    char a[50];
    printf("Select the conversion : \n"); // Inch-centimeter conversion

    printf("Inch to centimeter : write ( Inch , inch ) \n");

    printf("Centimeter to inch : write ( Cm , cm )\n");

    scanf("%s", a);

    if (strcmp(a, "Cm") || strcmp(a , "cm") == 0)
    {

        printf("Enter the number in centimeter: ");
        scanf("%lf", &i);

        cm = 0.393701 * i;
        printf("%.2lf in centimeter is %lf inch ", i, cm);
    }

    else if (strcmp(a, "Inch") || strcmp(a, "inch") == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter the number in inch:\n");
        scanf("%lf", &cm);

        i = 2.54 * cm;
        printf("%.2lf in inch is %lf centimeter\n", cm, i);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Written wrong parameter , try again !\n");
    }


}
```

Comment: You probably meant `if (strcmp(a, "Cm") == 0 || strcmp(a , "cm") == 0)`, same with the else. You might consider just converting the input to all lowercase or using a case insensitive compare.

Comment: Read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and compile your code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source software like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Consider using [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) to generate a parser

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes i meant it , why it is same with else ? i want in else if statement to be like `else if (strcmp(a, "Inch") || strcmp(a, "inch") == 0)` but is works as in if statement idk why  ( btw sorry for my english , i am bad at it )

Comment: Voting to close this as a typo. It doesn't work in the `if` branch. It almost always goes into the `if` branch

Answer (score 0):

See [strcmp - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) for a reference:

```c
int strcmp( const char *lhs, const char *rhs );
```

**Return Value**

> Negative value if lhs appears before rhs in lexicographical order.
>
> Zero if lhs and rhs compare equal.
>
> Positive value if lhs appears after rhs in lexicographical order.

Let's take your `if` and `else if` to analyse:

```c
if (strcmp(a, "Cm") || strcmp(a, "cm") == 0)
```

The `if` statement combines two statement with `||`, if any one below is true, it will be true:

1. `strcmp(a, "Cm")`: it will be true when any string you input appears after "Cm" in lexicographical order, many string will go into this, like your "Inch, inch", also like "d"... but if you input "Cm", it will be 0 then false, "cm" will be positive then true
2. `strcmp(a, "cm") == 0`: it will be true when your input exactly equals "cm"

so, when you input "cm|inch|Inch", the if will be true

Look the `else if`:

```c
else if (strcmp(a, "Inch") || strcmp(a, "inch") == 0)
```

As the analyse above, only can "Cm" go to this judgement, and "Cm" appears after "Inch" in lexicographical order, so it is true.

I think maybe you want to express the code below as your `if` and `else if` statement.

```c
if (strcmp(a, "Cm") == 0 || strcmp(a, "cm") == 0) {
    ...
}
else if (strcmp(a, "Inch") == 0 || strcmp(a, "inch") == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Wish these can help you. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Omgg i forgooottt ittt , thank you very much !!